# Send push notification to only one device when a user's logged in multiple devices

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification, sdk

I'm looking for some ways to send push messages to only one device when a contact is logged in multiple devices.(ipad, iphone..etc), and I'd like to specifically target the last logged-in one.

I found the  HELP document about this, but it's not the solution we're looking for, since it does not target the last logged-in device and it also doesn't block specific devices from receiving messages if it does not meet certain criteria.

Here's the HELP URL regarding this.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_FAQ_product.htm&type=5

How can we make sure that we target the last logged-in device when users have multiple devices login?

Comment: Please don't @-mention specific SFSE users. Doing it in the original question also has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably going to involve an Attribute and some evaluation in a data extension.

For the Attribute, set an value for `loginDate` (or similar) and apply a timestamp when the user logs into your application. Then you would have your data extension evaluate each contact's `loginDate` and choose only the most recent.

Let me qualify that by saying, I'm not sure if the 2nd part is even possible, and for setting an ever changing value for an Attribute you need to be very careful to not implement bad code that might register your contacts over, and over, and over ... which could get you throttled on the server side. The best practice for values like this is `only set them when your UI is visible` and `only set them for events like a login` *NOT* for things like app opened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution you've provided would be the most ideal one, but it concerns me about the server-side issues, as you mentioned.
So we are also thinking about the ways that delete all the device IDs except the last one, so that it can easily evaluate the last login trials. It still concerns me about the risk of deleting data., but would there be any ways to implement this?

Comment: At the risk of sounding condescending, and I do not mean it that way at all, you will mess up the data deletion. Don't do that. If you're at a loss then engage with Salesforce's Solutions and Services teams for help.